# SubRip-File-Parser Unable to detect file encoding

Tags: php, file, srt, webvtt

I'm trying to get this srt to vtt converter to work, but it keep saying "Unable to detect file encoding" when trying, here is my code.

```
require('src/SrtParser/srtFile.php');
if(isset($_POST['convert'])){
    try{
        $file = new \SrtParser\srtFile('./subtitle.srt');

        // display the text of the first entry
        echo $file->getSub(0)->getText();
        $file->mergeSrtFile($file2);
        $file->build();
        $file->save('./new_subtitles.vtt');

    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong, the files are linked correct.

Link to file-parser on GitHub [delphiki/SubRip-File-Parser](https://github.com/delphiki/SubRip-File-Parser)

Comment: Uh, is `exec` enabled? Can you use the function `exec`? The Parser relies on it.

Comment: As the github readme says, the project is no longer maintained and moved to https://github.com/captioning/captioning. Alternatively you could try the new project.

Comment: I never understood why people implement code to try to detect a text files character encoding. It is obvious that this simply is not possible in any reliable way. You sometimes can prove that a certain file can _not_ be encoded in some multi byte encoding, but it is impossible to detect a file encoding in a general manner. _Any_ file can be considered to hold text in a valid 8 bit encoding. And it is impossible to differ between different 8bit encodings without guessing or using some heuristics which obviously cannot be precise.

Comment: I did try [github.com/captioning/captioning](https://github.com/captioning/captioning), cant get it to work, it gives me an error in saying `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Captioning\Format\SubripFile' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/websites/srt_to_vtt/index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/websites/srt_to_vtt/index.php on line 5` Anyone? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend opening file in Notepad++ and converting encoding to UTF-8.

---

Or you can use:

```
Subtitles::convert('subtitles.srt', 'new_subtitles.vtt');
```

https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles